# get access to child content in expandable list view

Tags: android, eclipse, expandablelistview

I used this code to get selected item in Expandable List and get its text and print it in log. but log show this `a.b.ExpandListChild@41cc3c90` and item that I clicked contain other text this `1`. I want to acess to this text `1` this is shown in list view.

```
ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int group_position, int child_position, long id)
    {
        if(group_position==0 && child_position==0){

            startActivity(intent);
            ExpandableListAdapter itemAdapter=parent.getExpandableListAdapter(); 
            String selectedItem=""+itemAdapter.getChild(group_position, child_position);
          //  String country = ""+ExpAdapter.getChild(group_position, child_position);


            Log.i("ddd", ""+selectedItem);




         } else if(group_position==2 && child_position==2){
         }
        return false;
    }
});
```

all code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> ExpListItems;
    private ExpandableListView ExpandList;
    ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpList);
        ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
        ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(MainActivity.this, ExpListItems);
        ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);

        final Intent intent= new Intent (this, zero.class); 

        ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int group_position, int child_position, long id)
            {
                if(group_position==0 && child_position==0){
                    startActivity(intent);
                    ExpandableListAdapter itemAdapter=parent.getExpandableListAdapter(); 
                    String selectedItem=""+itemAdapter.getChild(group_position, child_position);
                    //String country = ""+ExpAdapter.getChild(group_position, child_position);


                    Log.i("ddd", ""+selectedItem);
                }
                else if(group_position==2 && child_position==2){
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ExpandList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int itemType = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id);

                if(itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {

                    int groupPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(id);

                    Log.i("s", "removepos");

                    if ( itemType == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
                        int childPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(id);
                      }
                    list.remove(groupPosition);

                    ExpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
                   return true;
                }
            });
        }

        public boolean onContextItemSelected1(MenuItem item) {
            ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            //String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
            int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);

            if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
                int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
                removeGroup(groupPos);
                ExpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return false;
        }


        public ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> SetStandardGroups() {
            list = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
            String[] listlist= new String[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
            String[] names= new String[] {"one","two","three"}; 
            for ( int i=0 ; i<3 ;i++)
            {
                ArrayList<ExpandListChild> list2 = new ArrayList<ExpandListChild>();

                ExpandListGroup gru1 = new ExpandListGroup();
                gru1.setName(names[i]);

                for ( int k=i*3 ; k<(i+1)*3 ;k++){
                    ExpandListChild ch1_1 = new ExpandListChild();
                    ch1_1.setName(listlist[i]);
                    ch1_1.setTag(null);
                    list2.add(ch1_1);
                }
                gru1.setItems(list2);
                list.add(gru1);
            }
            return list;
        }


        public void dialog (long id)
        {
            final int position=(int) id;
            //String number=list.get(position);
            list.remove(position);
            ExpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void removeGroup(int group) {
            //TODO: Remove the according group. Dont forget to remove the children aswell!
            Log.v("Adapter", "Removing group"+group);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think error is here

```
String selectedItem=""+itemAdapter.getChild(group_position, child_position);
```

`itemAdapter.getChild(...)` has return type of Object. When you print an object it will print the default toString() implementation of the Object class.
[Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

**Answer:** Cast the `getChild(...)` to the Adapter Item type and use it.

Comment: how cast it to Adapter Item type ?

Comment: Check this out:[Expand list view tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: You have to override the getchild(...) in your custom ExpandListAdapter.